# Tween on background position doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

anyone can explain me why

```
$(''+this.get("rel")+'-arrow').tween("margin-top",-10);
```

work and

```
$(''+this.get("rel")+'-arrow').tween("background-position","center -10px");
```

doesn't work?
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All animation methods animate values that are numerical, `center` is not, and actually, you shouldn't be using `center`, it's `50%`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bejD4/

```
document.getElement('div').tween('background-position', '50% 100px');
```

Comment: The resulting position is `50px 100px`, since the tween option `unit` is set to `px` by default. To get the correct result, you must calculate how much pixels 50% is and use that value...